# Nested If to LINQ and Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, enumeration, enumerate

Net 6.0

Our company uses a metric layout that takes records that look like this

```
AAA|0000A|000AA|0001A
AAA|0000A|000AA|0002A
AAA|0000A|000AB|0001B
AAA|0000A|000AB|0002B
AAA|0000B|000BA|0001A
AAA|0000B|000BB|0001B
```

and transforms it into this

```
AAA|BLANK|BLANK|BLANK

AAA|0000A|BLANK|BLANK
AAA|0000B|BLANK|BLANK

AAA|0000A|000AA|BLANK
AAA|0000A|000AB|BLANK
AAA|0000B|000BA|BLANK
AAA|0000B|000BB|BLANK

AAA|0000A|000AA|0001A
AAA|0000A|000AA|0002A
AAA|0000A|000AA|0003A
AAA|0000A|000AA|0004A
AAA|0000A|000AB|0001B
AAA|0000A|000AB|0002B
AAA|0000B|000BA|0001A
AAA|0000B|000BB|0001B
```

I have a custom object

```
public class HierarchyStructure
{
    public string Employer { get; set; }
    public string Level1 { get; set; }
    public string Level2 { get; set; }
    public string Level3 { get; set; }
    public string Level4 { get; set; }
    public bool isRxlvl3 { get; set; }
    public bool isExpired { get; set; }
    public string lvl4SubType { get; set; }

    public HierarchyStructure(string employer,
                              string? level1 = null,
                              string? level2 = null,
                              string? level3 = null,
                              string? level4 = null,
                              bool isRxlvl3 = false,
                              bool isExpired = false,
                              string? lvl4SubType = null)
    {
        this.Employer = employer;
        this.Level1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(level1) ? string.Empty : level1;
        this.Level2 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(level2) ? string.Empty : level2;
        this.Level3 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(level3) ? string.Empty : level3;
        this.Level4 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(level4) ? string.Empty : level4;
        this.isRxlvl3 = isRxlvl3;
        this.isExpired = isExpired;
        this.lvl4SubType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(lvl4SubType) ? string.Empty : lvl4SubType;
    }

}
```

I am trying to populate from a static level into a formatted output list

```
    private List<HierarchyStructure> AllLevels => _allLevels;
    private List<HierarchyStructure> LocationLevels => _LocationLevels;
```

I developed methods for each level call, but I can't figure out how to merge them into one method that either calls itself recursively or dynamically selects the right values. I do not think it is possible to combine these due to the different comparisons and return values.

```
    public bool GetDistinctEmployers()
    {

        var selectedLevels = (from levels in AllLevels
                              select new HierarchyStructure(levels.Employer));

        foreach(HierarchyStructure level in selectedLevels) LocationLevels.Add(level);

        return true;
    }

    public bool GetDistinctLevel1(string emp)
    {

        var selectedLevels = (from levels in AllLevels
                              where levels.Employer == emp
                              select new HierarchyStructure(levels.Employer,levels.Level1));

        foreach(HierarchyStructure level in selectedLevels) LocationLevels.Add(level);

        return true;

    }

    public bool GetDistinctLevel2(string lvl)
    {

        var selectedLevels = (from levels in AllLevels
                              where levels.Level1 == lvl
                              select new HierarchyStructure(levels.Employer,levels.Level1, levels.Level2));

        foreach(HierarchyStructure level in selectedLevels) LocationLevels.Add(level);

        return true;

    }

    public bool GetDistinctLevel3(string lvl)
    {

        var selectedLevels = (from levels in AllLevels
                              where levels.Level2 == lvl
                              select new HierarchyStructure(levels.Employer,levels.Level1, levels.Level2, levels.Level3));

        foreach(HierarchyStructure level in selectedLevels) LocationLevels.Add(level);

        return true;

    }

    public bool GetDistinctLevel4(string lvl)
    {

        var selectedLevels = (from levels in AllLevels
                              where levels.Level3 == lvl
                              select new HierarchyStructure(levels.Employer,levels.Level1, levels.Level2, levels.Level3, levels.Level4));

        foreach(HierarchyStructure level in selectedLevels) LocationLevels.Add(level);

        return true;

    }
```

When I try and combine all these together, it ends up being soooo nested and I feel like there must be a better way to accomplish this. I am fairly certain this level of nesting will error my quality gate on my pipeline.

```
    public void ProcessLevels()
    {
        if(GetDistinctEmployers())
        {
            foreach(string employer in AllLevels.Select(x => x.Employer))
            {
                if(GetDistinctLevel1(employer))
                {
                    foreach(string level1 in AllLevels.Select(x => x.Level1))
                    {
                        if(GetDistinctLevel2(level1))
                        {
                            foreach(string level2 in AllLevels.Select(x => x.Level2))
                            {
                                if(GetDistinctLevel3(level2))
                                {
                                    foreach(string level3 in AllLevels.Select(x => x.Level3))
                                    {
                                        if(GetDistinctLevel4(level3))
                                        {
                                            SaveData();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I am also getting another inline quality flag that my expressions in this block can be shortened using LINQ. I dont understand how my one line can be simplified.

```
...AllLevels.Select(x => x.Employer)
...AllLevels.Select(x => x.Level1)
... etc
```

A view of the data output I am trying to get.

[image: View of Desired Data Output]

Update: Thank you for the help offered - using the answers provided in this thread, I have coded my solution like this eliminating a lot of loops.

```
    public void ProcessLevels()
    {
        var employers = AllLevels.Where(x=> !x.isExpired ).Select(x => x.Employer).Distinct();
        var lvl1 = AllLevels.Where(x=> !x.isExpired ).Select(x => new {x.Employer, x.Level1 }).Distinct();
        var lvl2 = AllLevels.Where(x=> !x.isExpired ).Select(x => new {x.Employer, x.Level1, x.Level2 }).Distinct();
        var lvl3 = AllLevels.Where(x=> !x.isExpired ).Select(x => new {x.Employer, x.Level1, x.Level2, x.Level3 }).Distinct();
        var lvl4 = AllLevels.Where(x=> !x.isExpired ).Select(x => new {x.Employer, x.Level1, x.Level2, x.Level3, x.Level4 }).Distinct();

        foreach(var emp in employers) { LocationLevels.Add(new LevelHierarchyStructure(emp)); }
        foreach(var lvl in lvl1) { LocationLevels.Add(new LevelHierarchyStructure(lvl.Employer, lvl.Level1)); }
        foreach(var lvl in lvl2) { LocationLevels.Add(new LevelHierarchyStructure(lvl.Employer, lvl.Level1, lvl.Level2)); }
        foreach(var lvl in lvl3) { LocationLevels.Add(new LevelHierarchyStructure(lvl.Employer, lvl.Level1, lvl.Level2, lvl.Level3)); }
        foreach(var lvl in lvl4) { LocationLevels.Add(new LevelHierarchyStructure(lvl.Employer, lvl.Level1, lvl.Level2, lvl.Level3, lvl.Level4)); }

        SaveData();
    }
```

I assume someone will flag me for posting my update, but im posting it so ppl understand what i did and see my final solution

Comment: I am sorry. I have no clue what you are trying to do here. Even the first transformation example doesn't add up for me. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I added an image of what the end data I am trying to get. It's taking a data table and matrixing out every value including blank values.

Comment: Using a tree did not cross your mind?

Comment: can you link me some articles? I'm not sure what to search for keywords.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)

Comment: A question regarding your desired result: should rows 4 and 200 be preceded by a level 3 row?

Comment: @TN yea - as long as the row is acounted for somewhere in my loop, the specific order wont matter too much. in the end i send this as a structured item into a stored proc into a database for consumers to query. it allows us to enable consumers to rapidly pull these values. the blanks mean something in the control displays.

Comment: What is "a metric layout"?

Comment: we translate blanks into a numeric metric (1,2,3...n) based of which column it is and then there is also a value associated with it in a lookup table. I've used a few different things from this post and have come up with a solution that gives me the proper results :)

Comment: @Nyra - Can you please provide feedback on my answer?

Comment: @Nyra - Please post your solution as an answer and not at the end of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need something that first expands each source row into all of the possible levels, and runs those results through a .Distinct() and an .OrderBy().

Given:

```
AAA|0000A|000AA|0001A
AAA|0000A|000AA|0002A
AAA|0000A|000AB|0001B
AAA|0000A|000AB|0002B
AAA|0000B|000BA|0001A
AAA|0000B|000BB|0001B
```

The expanded data would be:

```
AAA
AAA|0000A
AAA|0000A|000AA
AAA|0000A|000AA|0001A
AAA
AAA|0000A
AAA|0000A|000AA
AAA|0000A|000AA|0002A
...
AAA
AAA|0000B
AAA|0000B|000BB
AAA|0000B|000BB|0001B
```

Then a .Distinct() and .OrderBy()

```
AAA
AAA|0000A
AAA|0000A|000AA
AAA|0000A|000AA|0001A
AAA|0000A|000AA|0002A
...
AAA|0000B
AAA|0000B|000BB
AAA|0000B|000BB|0001B
...
```

You would need a generating function to expand each source row into an enumerated list than can be fed into a .SelectMany(), and may also need to define custom comparators to be used by the .Distinct() and a .OrderBy() functions.

Something like:

```
private static IEnumerable<HierarchyStructure> HierarchyGenerator(this HierarchyStructure level)
{
    yield return new HierarchyStructure(levels.Employer);
    yield return new HierarchyStructure(levels.Employer,levels.Level1);
    yield return new HierarchyStructure(levels.Employer,levels.Level1, levels.Level2);
    yield return new HierarchyStructure(levels.Employer,levels.Level1, levels.Level2, levels.Level3);
    yield return new HierarchyStructure(levels.Employer,levels.Level1, levels.Level2, levels.Level3, levels.Level4);
}
...
LocationLevels = AllLevels
    .SelectMany(levels => levels.HierarchyGenerator())
    .Distinct(...custom HierarchyStructure IEqualityComparer...)
    .OrderBy(hier => hier, ...custom HierarchyStructure IComparer...)
    .ToList();
```

There are other ways, such as generating distinct values are each level, unioning them all together, and then feeding them to the sort.

Something like:

```
var level0 = AllLevels
    .Select(levels => newHierarchyStructure(levels.Employer))
    .Distinct(IEqualityComparer...);
...
var level4 = AllLevels
    .Select(levels => new HierarchyStructure(levels.Employer,levels.Level1, levels.Level2, levels.Level3, levels.Level4))
    .Distinct(IEqualityComparer...);

LocationLevels = level0
    .Union(level1)
    .Union(level2)
    .Union(level3)
    .Union(level4)
    .OrderBy(hier => hier, ...custom HierarchyStructure IComparer...)
    .ToList();
```

There may be some performance tradeoffs in selecting where the distinct operations are applied. Using intermediate anonymous objects might also help, such as:

```
var level1 = AllLevels
    .Select(levels => new {levels.Employer, levels.Level1})
    .Distinct()
    .Select(levels => new HierarchyStructure(levels.Employer,levels.Level1));
```

Here the `.Distinct()` uses the default comparator for the anonymous object, which compares each contained value.

The custom comparers can also be incorporated into the `HierarchyStructure` class by implementing the `IComparable` interface. The `HierarchyGenerator()` function could also be made a member function within the `HierarchyStructure` class.

(My apologies in advance for any syntax errors. This is untested. I'll update the above given any comments.)

Comment: this helps a LOT! i am actually in middle of editing my expressions for their distinct and saw this post lol i can use this to work through my existing code ty ty

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be able to be solved quite easily with LINQ.

I'll start with this `input`:

```
string[] input = new[]
{
    "AAA|0000A|000AA|0001A",
    "AAA|0000A|000AA|0002A",
    "AAA|0000A|000AB|0001B",
    "AAA|0000A|000AB|0002B",
    "AAA|0000B|000BA|0001A",
    "AAA|0000B|000BB|0001B",
};
```

Now I can transform this into the `output` like this:

```
string[][] parts = input.Select(x => x.Split('|')).ToArray();

int max = parts.Max(p => p.Length);

string[][] expanded =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, max)
        .SelectMany(i => parts.Select(p => p.Take(i + 1).ToArray()).ToArray())
        .DistinctBy(xs => String.Join("|", xs))
        .OrderBy(xs => String.Join("|", xs))
        .ToArray();

string[] output =
    expanded
        .Select(e => String.Join("|", e))
        .ToArray();
```

That gives me:

```
AAA
AAA|0000A
AAA|0000A|000AA
AAA|0000A|000AA|0001A
AAA|0000A|000AA|0002A
AAA|0000A|000AB
AAA|0000A|000AB|0001B
AAA|0000A|000AB|0002B
AAA|0000B
AAA|0000B|000BA
AAA|0000B|000BA|0001A
AAA|0000B|000BB
AAA|0000B|000BB|0001B
```

If you just want to stop to fill a grid, just use `expanded`.

With this approach it doesn't matter how many levels deep the source data is.

Comment: this is a good option to solve dynamically. I think it gives some useful insights on how to account for things dynamically. For my use I luckily know it will be limited to 5 levels. I think my pipes to signify data may have been confusing - those were to designate columns on a dataset. I have posted my final solution at end of my post which is very similar to the other answer here. I did give upvotes though for this useful approach - tysm :)